# Approximating a polynomial to a piece-wise function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, polynomials

I was going through my introductory calculus book(for high-school student) by a Russian author(N.Psikunov) where I encountered a theorem without proof named:

**Weierstrass Approximation Theorem**

So how can we apply this theorem and apply it to piece wise functions?(any general approach?)(say a simple function like |x|)

Comment: For example, read the section *Approximating Continuous Functions" in this Wiki article on Bernstein polynomials, and implement it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial

Comment: @gt6989b: there 's little discussion of bernstein polynomial(apporximation) (no proof..just a mention and how to use it on [0,1] interval )and a brief mention of Cheybyshev Polynomials and I am unable to comprehend them as I only have mathematical background of high-school student

Comment: i thought you were asking given a particular $f(x)$ how do i construct a polynomial within $\epsilon$ of $f(x)$. If you were asking something different, please explain what it is you are looking for.

Comment: I am asking for a generic approach that applies to wide variety of f(x)(piece-wise) which helps  to construct a polynomial within ϵ of f(x)(piece-wise) and which I am able to comprehend at this level(high-school maths..tho I won't mind and avance answer as it can be used as future reference)