# How to prove that constructible length is 'algebraic'?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

Hey while going through this answer by Charles Slade to this question on quora :

[I JUST SQUARED the CIRCLE! I found a way to do it using only a compass and straight edge and was only off by 0.06 of a square inch in area. What now?](https://www.quora.com/I-JUST-SQUARED-the-CIRCLE-I-found-a-way-to-do-it-using-only-a-compass-and-straight-edge-and-was-only-off-by-0-06-of-a-square-inch-in-area-What-now)

He states that

> "the length of any line segment you can construct [*with compass and straightedge*] is, in fact, algebraic. Meaning, the length is a root of some polynomial with rational coefficients."

SO how can I go about proving it?

**EDiT**:*put on hold as unclear what you're asking by mrf, LutzL, Sawarnik, Joey Zou, Shailesh 2 days ago
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking*

TO Mods/Whomever-Concerned : I'm a High-school student and I don't have graduate mathematical training.The question indirectly asked on quora about squaring a circle,I also had same question but I was given same excuse like OP:Galois theory,Algebra,etc...
I stumbled across this answer posted on quora  and came across the given :

> "the length of any line segment you can construct [*with compass and straightedge*] is, in fact, algebraic. Meaning, the length is a root of some polynomial with rational coefficients."

I attempted to prove it myself but I can't prove it.Tried to google it but couldn't do it

So I posted it here to see if anybody out here can help me prove or intuitively understand the above thing using only high-school level math?

^To be more precise :a standard math course equivalent to that taught in Soviet/Russian schools

Comment: It is well known that it is impossible to square the circle with straight edge and compass. And by *well known* I mean that it has been proven (using Galois theory, if I remember correctly).

Comment: The author states *"[...] the length of any line segment you can construct is, in fact, algebraic. Meaning, the length is a root of some polynomial with rational coefficients."* Please do not paraphrase precise mathematical statements with vague phrases like "length is algebraic." See the Wikipedia article on [constructible numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number).

Comment: @arctictern:made changes as suggested

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: to be pedantic, the proof has nothing to do with Galois theory itself, only the more basic properties of degrees of extensions. On the other hand, these proofs fit so nicely with the material in a course on Galois theory that you will rarely find them anywhere else!

Comment: @Nefertiti Thanks for the clarification. I remembered I had seen it in the context of Galois theory in my algebra course, I wasn't sure it used actual Galois theory.

Comment: @Nefertiti:Can you guys please proof as answer rather than discussing among yoursef in comments :(

Comment: I am sympathetic to your cause, and I applaud you for being a curious high school student. However I should probably tell you that there are a lot of mathematical statements that are very easy to formulate and explain, and do not have an accessible elementary proof. This is one of the magical things about mathematics, how to prove a statement so easy to describe, we need to use heavy machinery.

Comment: (Incidentally, it was the teacher who taught me Galois theory (eventually), who told me once that there are statements in number theory that a third grader can understand, but we have no idea how to prove them, or that their proof uses incredibly complex tools. Case in point, just look at Fermat's Last Theorem and the tools needed for its proof.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: thank you for your kind invaluable  comments.I already had intuition regarding that this question won't yield a fruitful answer for me...I just posted the question cause 0.01 probability of getting an answer is much greater than 0 by not asking the question!

Comment: @AsafKaragila:I don't know if this goesa long with MathSe's policy but can you answer these: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917950/approximating-a-polynomial-to-a-piece-wise-function , http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974622/periodic-functions-inducing-multiple-roots-to-a-apparentlinear-equations

Answer (score 1):

The linked question is of course non-sensical, the quoted
**"was only off by 0.06 of a square inch in area"** tells you exactly that the allegedly algebraic number that was constructed is not $2\pi$, the circumference of the unit circle.

An approximation is not an exact value. The algebraic numbers are dense, as are the rational numbers, in the real numbers. The properties of an approximation do not translate automatically into properties of the exact value.

---

After guessing what you really mean, i.e., that you referred to the first answer in the linked site, not the question, I first invite you to read again the full answer on quora. One can not provide a better answer in the frame provided here.

As was said in the comments, by *arctic tern* esp., your original question does not describe what you probably mean. The fact that any length you can construct with compass and straightegde is algebraic (in the coordinates of the given points) is a key fact of analytical geometry and contained in the theory of [constructible numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number).

Comment: In what way does this answer my query?

Comment: I enhanced your question with the full quote that you almost surely referred to and changed the answer appropriately.

Comment: Respected Sir,I made changes to questions as deemed by the the community